# Playing .mp3 from internal storage android

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

I know there are several questions about this, sadly none of them helps me. (or I am too stupid to apply the answer to my problem).

On my virtual phone I created the folder "Musik" inside this folder a "King.mp3" is located.

I am not able to play this mp3 via media player.

This is the crucial part of my code:

```
MediaPlayer mp;
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+
                "/Musik/King.mp3"));
mp.start();
```

I already tried it with:

```
mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+
                    "/Musik/King.mp3");
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

but it is still not working.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nINGk.png

(I know there is a lot of useless stuff in the code, I just wanted to show the mp3 path (on the right).

I tried pasting the mp3 directly into the "sdcard".

i dont even care if the path would be hard coded like "/storage/sdcard/Musik" (already tried, its not working. not even with mnt/sdcard/Musik

Comment: Do you get any logcat output when you try to play the file?  Like "Permission Denied"?

Comment: http://pastebin.de/127190 this is the log.

Comment: Your getting null pointer in line 88 (StartActivity.java:88), what are in this line?

Comment: Titeldauer = mp.getDuration();  i am trying to get the duration from the song. i need this for later so i can start the song at the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify what path "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()" is?  Maybe it is not what you expect it to be.  This path doesn't necessarily always point to the external sd card location.

Answer (score 0):

Please check:

http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2988

You're probably using the wrong path o no permission. I recommend you to check the path and check if exits with [File.exists() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29).

Comment: ty. i now found out that Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/Musik/" exists. but as soon as i add +"King.mp3" it doesnt exist. What am i gonna do about it? as you can see in the screenshot i added the mp3 files. maybe it only allows lower case letters? like king? i will try it.

Comment: check with monitor.bat -> File Explorer . if king.mp3 exists and also the permissions.

Comment: permissions is "-rwxrwx---" as it says in DDMS in eclipse.
i dont know what you mean about monitor.bat, i googled it

Comment: maybe it helps: if i open the stock musicplayer on the emulator he finds the song. and i can also play it.